# Clean up async function in an useEffect React hook

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I have the following useEffect function and trying to find the best way to clean this up when the component unmounts.

I thought it would be best to follow the `makeCancelable` from the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html), however, the code still executes when the promise is cancelled.

```
const makeCancelable = (promise) => {
  let hasCanceled_ = false;

  const wrappedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promise.then(
      val => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : resolve(val),
      error => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : reject(error)
    );
  });

  return {
    promise: wrappedPromise,
    cancel() {
      hasCanceled_ = true;
    },
  };
};
```

```
//example useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const collectionRef_1 = await firestore.collection(...)
    const collectionRef_2 = await firestore.collection(...)
    if (collectionRef_1.exists) {
      //update local state
      //this still runs!
    }
    if (collectionRef_2.exists) {
      //update local state
      //and do does this!
    }
  }
  const getDataPromise = makeCancelable(new Promise(getData))
  getDataPromise.promise.then(() => setDataLoaded(true))
  return () => getDataPromise.cancel()
}, [dataLoaded, firestore])
```

I have also tried `const getDataPromise = makeCancelable(getData)` without any luck. The code executes fine, just doesn't clean up correctly when the component unmounts.

Do I need to also cancel the two await functions?

Comment: `makeCancelable(new Promise(getData))` I'd say this should be `makeCancelable(getData())` notice function call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `makeCancelable` function you are just checking the value of `hasCanceled_` **after the promise has finished** (meaning `getData` has already executed entirely):

```js
const makeCancelable = (promise) => {
  let hasCanceled_ = false;

  const wrappedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // AFTER PROMISE RESOLVES (see following '.then()'!), check if the 
    // react element has unmount (meaning the cancel function was called). 
    // If so, just reject it
    promise.then(
      val => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : resolve(val),
      error => hasCanceled_ ? reject({isCanceled: true}) : reject(error)
    );
  });

  return {
    promise: wrappedPromise,
    cancel() {
      hasCanceled_ = true;
    },
  };
};
```

Instead, in this case I would recomend you to go for a simpler and more classic solution and use a `isMounted` variable to create the logic you want:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true
  const getData = async () => {
    const collectionRef_1 = await firestore.collection(...)
    const collectionRef_2 = await firestore.collection(...)
    if (collectionRef_1.exists && isMounted) {
      // this should not run if not mounted
    }
    if (collectionRef_2.exists && isMounted) {
      // this should not run if not mounted
    }
  }
  getData().then(() => setDataLoaded(true))
  return () => {
    isMounted = false
  }
}, [dataLoaded, firestore])
```

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now by checking it after, rather than cancelling it during. I will try to rework my useEffect to get this working. React states that doing an isMounted check is an anti-pattern to trying to avoid doing this.

Comment: Maybe these docs only apply to class components? Because you can see Facebook implementing this "antipattern" with hooks in the Relay docs https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/step-by-step#23-fetching-graphql-from-react

Comment: I think you could be right. The example in the docs is using classes!

Comment: BTW, found the same pattern (named`ignore` instead of `isMounted`) in the own React Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: Awesome, I have adjusted my function to use this approach and it works great. I have added a link in the question to where react stated this was an anti-pattern. But as you mentioned, it's becoming more clear that this was just for classes.